# Vim syntax highlighting for continued comments until next keyword

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting

I have code like this:

```
# some comment
comment  This is a comment \
         that continues.
keyword option=3.123e4
```

Comments start with either "#" or "comment" and can continue with "\" and a line break.
I would like to match the next line after the last "\" as well or until a keyword from the list.
Here is what I have:

```
syn match atlasComment "#.*$"
syn match atlasComment "comment.*$"
syn keyword myKeyword keyword anotherKW nextgroup=myOption skipwhite
syn keyword myOption option
```

Is it possible to use a range from "comment" to a specifiet keyword from list of keywords that are highlighted anyway? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find some useful hints at `:help :syn-oneline`.

> The "oneline" argument indicates that the region does not cross a line
>   boundary.  It must match completely in the current line.  However, when the
>   region has a contained item that does cross a line boundary, it continues on
>   the next line anyway.  A contained item can be used to recognize a line
>   continuation pattern.

This leads to the following solution:

```
:syn region atlasComment start="comment" end="$" oneline contains=atlasCommentContinuation
:syn match atlasCommentContinuation "\\$" contained
```

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed the online argument.